# How do I remove the "Next Appointment" and "Previous Appointment" tabs on the month view in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

I find the "Next Appointment" and "Previous Appointment" tabs that show up in Outlook 2013 to be pretty useless.

As you can see in the screenshot below, they're actually obscuring parts of the calendar when it's in the month view.

Is there a way to get rid of those tabs? Or am I stuck with them whenever there isn't a visible appointment on my calendar?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution at the bottom of [here](http://www.outlookbanter.com/outlook-calandaring/67693-how-do-you-remove-previous.html)

Unfortunately, the handles show up as long as there are no events visible on that view, so you're stuck with them unless you add a recurring monthly event to the calendar. Then the handles will disappear.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll just have to deal with them. I'm not sure I want to create a null recurring appointment just to get rid of those tabs.